# What is good for spell checker? Google spell checker or Hunspell

Tags: c#, asp.net, spell-checking, hunspell

For my asp.net website, I need spell check functionality. I found some interesting solutions to do it.
 
1. Google spell checker 
 2. Hunspell. 
 Both are free. For my understanding I realized some cons and pros for both approach.

For Google spell checker, it gives much more correct word for incorrect word but Hunspell gives several suggestions. And Google has up to date suggestions but Hunspell,it depends on Open Office dictionary. 
In my case, I need only one suggestion. 
For cons, I have to depend on Google for spell checking. If Google service is down, it will effect for my site too. 
 
So, what will be suitable for my site. Is it good idea to choose Google spell checker?
Is there are any non free solutions for spell checking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think, it's good to use Hunspell

Reason for using [Hunspell](http://www.maierhofer.de/en/open-source/nhunspell-net-spell-checker.aspx)

> NHunspell is based on Hunspell and brings the Open Office spell
>   checking, hyphenation and thesaurus to the Microsoft® .NET Framework.
>   NHunspell is a .NET (C#, VB) library and wraps the native libraries
>   Hunspell, Hyphen and MyThes.
>
> The integrated libraries are used in OpenOffice and work with the
>   dictionaries published on OpenOffice.org.
>
> NHunspell is licenced under: GPL/LGPL/MPL. Free use in commercial
>   applications is permitted according to the LGPL and MPL licenses. Your
>   commercial application can link against the NHunspell DLLs.

*From one of the comments:*

> > **Spell Checker: Hun­spell Hun­spell is a spell checker**,
> >
> > mor­pho­log­i­cal an­a­lyzer and gen­er­a­tor. It has stem­ming
> >     func­tions to find word stems. It al­lows the gen­er­a­tion of
> >     de­rived forms (plu­ral, ...) from the word stem.
>
> **Spel­lEngine - Spell Check**,
>
> Hyphen­ation and Th­e­saurus for Server
>   and Web Server (ASP.NET) Spel­lEngine al­lows the thread-safe
>   ex­e­cu­tion of spell check re­quests. It is a com­po­nent opimzed for
>   servers. All NHun­spell fea­tures (spell check, hy­phen­ation,
>   the­saurus, anal­y­sis and gen­er­a­tion) are in­te­grated. To en­sure
>   full uti­liza­tion of the CPUs on sev­eral re­quests, one Hun­spell,
>   Hyphen or MyThes is in­stan­ti­ated per pro­ces­sor or pro­ces­sor
>   core and con­trolled by a sem­a­phore. Mul­ti­ple dic­tio­nar­ies can
>   be in­stalled to serve dif­fer­ent lan­guages. Spell check,
>   hy­phen­ation, and syn­onyms in mul­ti­lin­gual ap­pli­ca­tions are
>   sup­ported with­out any ad­di­tional pro­gram­ming.

source: [1](http://www.maierhofer.de/en/open-source/nhunspell-net-spell-checker.aspx), [2](http://nhunspell.sourceforge.net/)